# Python 'function does not take keyword arguments' error using **kwargs with urequests

Tags: python, wifi, typeerror, traceback, micropython

Quick project overview: I'm trying to make a controller for my Philips Hue lights using a LoPy. To get information from the Hue API I need to make the connection (that works) and send information to the API, the problem is in that part.

Since the LoPy cannot use the 'requests' library I'm using the 'urequests' library, the functions that is used to send requests looks like this

*urequests.py*

```
def head(url, **kwargs):
    return request("HEAD", url, **kwargs)

def get(url, **kwargs):
    return request("GET", url, **kwargs)

def post(url, **kwargs):
    return request("POST", url, **kwargs)

def put(url, **kwargs):
    return request("PUT", url, **kwargs)

def patch(url, **kwargs):
    return request("PATCH", url, **kwargs)

def delete(url, **kwargs):
    return request("DELETE", url, **kwargs)
```

Using this library I'm using the 'qhue' library to get information about my lights, this works using the following function:

*qhue.py*

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    url = self.url
    for a in args:
        url += "/" + str(a)
    http_method = kwargs.pop('http_method',
        'get' if not kwargs else 'put').lower()
    if http_method == 'put':
        r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(kwargs, default=list), timeout=self.timeout)
    elif http_method == 'post':
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(kwargs, default=list), timeout=self.timeout)
    elif http_method == 'delete':
        r = requests.delete(url, timeout=self.timeout)
    else:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=self.timeout)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise QhueException("Received response {c} from {u}".format(c=r.status_code, u=url))
    resp = r.json()
    if type(resp) == list:
        errors = [m['error']['description'] for m in resp if 'error' in m]
        if errors:
            raise QhueException("\n".join(errors))
    return resp
```

So when I request the information of my lights the 'else' is being called in the qhue.py, thus calling the get() function in the urequests.py, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 279, in 
>     File "qhue.py", line 39, in **call**
>   TypeError: function does not take keyword arguments

*main.py code to get all lights (b = a function in qhue.py)*

```
lights = b.lights   # Creates a new Resource with its own URL
```

How does this error occur and how can I fix it? To me it seems that using **kwargs would allow the function to define it's own arguments (like timeout= and data=)